# $\varphi$ is integrable if and only if $f=g$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ continuous functions, with $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for every $x\in[a,b]$. Define $\varphi:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ by 
>   $$
> \varphi(x)=
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{cc}
> f(x) &,\mbox{ if } x\in\mathbb Q\cap[a,b],\\
> g(x) &,\mbox{ if } x\not\in\mathbb Q\cap[a,b].
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>   Prove that
>   $$
> \tag 1
> \underline{\int_a^b} \varphi(x)dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx\quad \mbox{ and }\quad \overline{\int_a^b} \varphi(x)dx = \int_a^b g(x)dx. 
> $$
>   Conclude that $\varphi$ is integrable if and only if $f=g$.

I already proved $(1)$ and $f=g \Longrightarrow \varphi$ integrable is obvious. I need help to prove that $\varphi$ integrable $\Longrightarrow f=g$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi$ is integrable then $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b g(x) \, dx$, or equivalently, $\displaystyle \int_a^b g(x) - f(x) \, dx = 0.$ If there is a single point $x_0 \in (a,b)$ with $f(x_0) < g(x_0)$, continuity gives you an $\epsilon > 0$ satisfying
$$(x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon) \subset (a,b)$$ and $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x \in (x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon)$. Then
$$0 = \int_a^b g(x) - f(x) \, dx \ge  \int_{x_0 - \epsilon}^{x_0 + \epsilon} g(x) - f(x) \, dx > 0 $$
which is a contradiction. Thus $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ and by continuity, for all $x \in [a,b]$ too.

Comment: I seem to be missing something.  Why does $\phi$ being (Riemann) integrable imply $\int_a^b(g(x)-f(x))dx=0$?

Comment: That is the *definition* of integrable.

Comment: How does the definition of integrable (for $\phi$) imply that relation?

Comment: That is the definition of Darboux integrable, which is equivalent to Riemann integrable.

Comment: I believe there is still a gap in the reasoning.  I believe it is necessary to use Darboux or Riemann integrability to imply continuity for $\phi$, forcing $f=\phi$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

$Q\cap [a,b]$ is a set of measure $0$.  Since $\phi (x)=g(x)$ almost everywhere, $\int_a^b\phi(x)dx=\int_a^bg(x)dx$, irrespectve of $f(x)$.

Comment: Did you read the problem tags?

Comment: @UmbertoP.  What problem tags?

Comment: My answer is based on the assumption that the integration of $\phi(x)$  is Lebesgue, not necessarily Riemann.  What happens on a set of measure $0$ doesn't matter.

Comment: The question is tagged "riemann-integration" so I think the intent of the questioner is clear.

Comment: Sorry!  I missed the tag.

Comment: Since $\phi(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable and the tag was about Riemann integrability, I assume that $\phi(x)$ is Riemann integrable and the integral is the same as the integral of $g(x)$  I believe that being Riemann integrable and equal to $f(x)$ (a continuous function) on all the rationals would make $\phi(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere, but I am not sure how to prove it.  In that case $f(x)=g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

If you have (1), then suppose that $\varphi$ is integrable, then upper and lower integrals should be the same number and then,
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^bg(x)dx$$
or qeuivalently
$$\int_a^b(g(x)-f(x))dx=0$$
But because $f(x)\le g(x)$, you have a nonnegative continuous function with zero integral. It isvery easy (by way of contradiction, for example) to see that this funcion must to be zero. Hence $f(x)-g(x)=0$.

Comment: Why does $\underline{\int_a^b}\phi(x)dx=\int_a^bf(x)dx$?  It has to be proved.

Comment: Given any nondegenerate interval $I\subset[a,b]$, $\sup_{x\in I} \varphi(x)=\sup_{x\in I}g(x)$ and $\inf_{x\in I} \varphi(x)=\inf_{x\in I}f(x)$. And this is true because ${\mathbb Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and hence ${\mathbb Q}\cap I$ is dense in $I$.

Comment: Your statement is true, but it still doesn't make the integral of $\phi$ = the integral of $f$.  I believe something like $\phi$ being Riemann integrable and therefore almost everywhere continuous is needed, but I'm not sure how to complete the argument.

Comment: If $\varphi$ is Riemann Integrable, both (upper and lower) integrals should be the same. Conversely, if $\int_a^bf=\int_a^bg$ then upper and lower integrals of $\varphi$ are the same and this is the definition of being Riemann integrable.

Comment: Your statements are true.  However how does it make the lower integral of $\phi$ equal to the integral of $f$?

Comment: Given any partition of $[a,b]$, say $P=\{a=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=b\}$, $\inf_{[x_k,x_{k+1}]}\varphi(x) =\inf_{[x_k,x_{k+1}]}f(x)$, so $L(\varphi,P)=L(f,P)$. Take supremum and you'll have $\underline{\int_a^b\varphi}=\int_a^bf$.

Comment: I get it!  What would happen if you didn't have $f\le g$ a given?

Comment: Then you have to know when (in which subinterval) $f\le g$ and in wich other $g\le f$.